# Histórico de accesos a Moodle por fecha

Tags: base-de-datos, moodle, estadística

He estado intentando obtener por medio de SQL generar una consulta que me permita, por fechas, obtener la cantidad de alumnos que ingresaron (Iniciaron sesion 1 vez al menos) al aula virtual, en la tabla `mdl_user` el campo `lastaccess` especifica eso, pero como su mismo nombre lo dice, es el ultimo acceso, no el histórico de accesos del usuario.

```
SELECT 
u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname, 
DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.lastaccess, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 6 HOUR) AS FechaU
FROM mdl_user u
WHERE DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.lastaccess, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 6 HOUR) >= @startdate
GROUP BY u.username;
```

De esta manera obtengo los usuarios que hicieron su ultimo acceso posterior a una fecha especifica (el día actual), pero quisiera saber como puedo obtener los usuarios que han ingresado por fechas.

Veo que en la tabla `mdl_sessions` se almacenan todas las sesiones de la plataforma, pero el número de registros haciendo el mismo `WHERE` a partir del campo `timecreated` no coinciden (talvez estoy entendiendo mal el campo `timecreated`), al tener esta consulta creo que por mi propia cuenta puedo llegar a hacer un `COUNT` por fecha y obtener el reporte que al final quisiera.

Muchas gracias!

psdt: las horas que le resto a la fecha es el ajuste horario que le debo hacer, el servidor esta en otro país y esa es la diferencia horaria que encaja con mi hora local.

Answer (score 0):

hay una tabla de Moodle, "mdl_log", que guarda toda la información de la actividad de los usuarios sobre la plataforma.